# Request is not redirected, when passes nginx

Tags: java, grails, nginx, spring-security

We have **Grails** application running on Tomcat. All requests to **80** port is redirected to **8080** by **Nginx**.
For security in our app we use **Spring Security**.

**So the problem** is: when user successfully log in to application, it must be redirected to another page, but it doesn't happen.

In Chrome browser nothing happens, in Firefox page "Corrupted Content Error" is shown.

**There is no problem** when we directly access application on port 8080. 
Problem also disappear when i manually delete cookie with jsessionid, but after first redirect it appears again and problem is in the same place.

**nginx conf:**

```
 server {
    limit_conn addr 10;
    listen externalIp:80;
    server_name serverName;
    root /var/ut/;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
            proxy_pass_header P3P;
    }

}
```

Comment: the configuration looks good. you may replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost. try to use listen 80; instead of externalIp:80. if this does not work, check your nginx version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, but not by nginx configuration.

I'v added this code to login action of auth controller:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session!=null && !session.isNew()) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
```

I don't really know why this problem exist, when my request passes nginx.
But this is hotfix for today.